# Spots on dog's skin

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition

Please help identifying the disorder documented on the photo, because something is not right with my dog and she is bothered by something with her skin. There's mild hair loss and flaky skin where the spots are worst.

[image]

Comment: can you add more information to your question like type of dog age of dog where in the world you are how long have the dog had this,the more details the more specific an answer can be.

Comment: How old is your dog?  These look like age spots, which most dogs and humans get.

Comment: hi thanks for helping! shes a golden retriever about 10 years old. i dont know about age spots. why does she act like her skins always irritated? these spots dont look so mich like a discoloration of skin but rather like a foreign thing, imho.

Comment: Could be allergies, dermatitis, mites, anything really so take to a vet

Answer (score 2):

Most skin issues cannot be diagnosed online and need to be seen by a veterinarian, many things can cause what you're seeing ranging from parasites, infection, thyroid disease etc.. Some tests may need to be ran to rule out issues either it be blood work, biopsies or skin scrapings depending on what the veterinarian sees in person.

Comment: i did take to a vet, and they said it was just allergies, but i examined it myself and i know it was parasites or something.